# Facebook Open Graph App: "Error occured"

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create a Washington Post-esque social reader for my self-hosted Wordpress site, so when someone reads a post of mine it's published on their Facebook newsfeed.

I've followed the Facebook Open Graph tutorial, but I continue to face a pop-up box saying "Error Occured" when I click "Read" on a post. I have used the debug tool and it reported that everything is okay.

Are there additional steps required to make an Open Graph app work on a self-hosted Wordpress site?

Below is the code I've used so far. I've replaced the actual Image URLs with defaults as I can't post images on Stack Overflow yet.

In the Meta Tag area I typed the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
 zeitlife: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/zeitlife#

<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="308222752522151" /> 
<meta property="og:type"        content="zeitlife:article" /> 
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.zeitlife.co.uk/cabana-brazilian-food-that-breaks-the-mould/> 
<meta property="og:title"       content="Cabana: Brazilian that Breaks the Mould"/> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Restaurant Review" /> 
<meta property="og:image"       content="[image URL]" /></a>[/caption]" />


 </head> 

 </html>
```

And in the body of the post I typed the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function postRead()
    {
    FB.api('/me/zeitlife:Read' + 
    '?article=http://zeitlife.co.uk/cabana-brazilian-food-that-breaks-the-mould','post',
     function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
    });
    }
    </script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
    FB.init({ 
        appId:'308222752522151', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true
    });
    </script>

    <fb:add-to-timeline></fb:add-to-timeline>

    <h3>
        <font size="18" face="verdana" color="blue">
            Cabana
        </font> 
    </h3> 
    <p>
        <img title="Cabana" 
                        src="Image url here" </p>       
<form> <input type="button" value="Read" onclick="postRead()" />
</form>
</html>
```

I would be eternally grateful if someone could help me out!

I look forward to your response.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You're making things a fair amount more difficult for yourself by creating a custom read action.

Facebook offers three built-in action types: reads, listens, and watches. (See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/)

If you use the built-in system:

- It's much easier to avoid errors
- Your articles appear in the "Trending articles" section of people's news feeds
- Facebook does most of the work setting up actions for you

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a space in:

http://www.zeitlife.co.uk/cabana-brazilian-food-that-breaks-the-mould /

It needs to be:

http://www.zeitlife.co.uk/cabana-brazilian-food-that-breaks-the-mould/

I tried using this at:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zeitlife.co.uk%2Fcabana-brazilian-food-that-breaks-the-mould%2F

And it worked.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! However, it still says error occured when I click the "Read" button. No problem comes up on the Debug tool, so I'm not sure what's wrong.